# Jquery fails when user changes tab

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 tabs.

Tab a: Make caculations using a progressbar. At the end of the process it have to close the ajax waiter and the progreessbar like this:

```
$(".results").css("display",""); 
$("#progressDialog").dialog("close");   
HideWait();
```

But if user changes to Tab b, and if the process ends inside the tab a, progressdialog is not closed, ajax waiter is not hidden and .results are not displayed and the object prevails o tab a.

How can i force to that object disappear. Thanks.

Comment: Not a lot to go on here. What does the code look like for switching tabs? How is this code called?

Comment: [MCVE] are great this is a bit too minimal though!

Comment: Code is not the problem.

Comment: When the user minimizes the window or switches to another tab, the bakground process go well, but the css o jquery changes are not applied.

This not about the code, is about the page visibility behavior.

Thanks for your help, Jon P your tutorial is not necessary.